# ClockTimer shows the value in second or ms?

Tags: c++

I have read this implementation in C++;

```
int ClockTimer::ClockMS()
{
   return clock() * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

double ClockTimer::CLOCK()
{
    return ClockMS() * 0.001;
}

void ClockTimer::StartTimer()
{   
   _time_start = ClockMS(); 
} 

void ClockTimer::StopTimer(int verb)
{
   _time_stop = ClockMS();
}


float ClockTimer::GetElapsedTime()
{
    return (_time_stop - _time_start)  * 0.001f;
}
```

I guess that the result of GetElapsedTime() is in milliseconds, is that right? Why is that?

Comment: Where did you hear that `clock()` measures elapsed time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `ClockMS` is returning milliseconds, then `GetElapsedTime` will return the time in seconds.  For example, if the elapsed time (the difference between stop and start) was 1000 ms, then the return value would be `1000 ms * .001 second/ms = 1 second`.